# jQuery toggle and mouseup conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, event-bubbling, mouseup

I have a simple button that toggles a menu onclick

If the menu is expanded/visible I hide it when clicking anywhere on the page (a part from the menu itself).

```
var menuBtn = $(".btn-menu"),
menuContainer = $(".menu"),
menuChildren = $(".menu").find("*");

menuBtn.on("click", function() {
    menuContainer.toggle();
});

$(window).mouseup(function(e){
    if(!menuContainer.is(e.target) && !menuChildren.is(e.target)){
        menuContainer.hide();
    }
});
```

When applying that function on mouseup, my toggle function no longer works. Menu will always stay open if clicking multiple times on the button (whereas it should hide & show).

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Dx6/)

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: worked for me in firefox and chrome

Comment: To reproduce the issue: click on menu button then click anywhere on the page and finally try again to click on the button. You'll see that toggle won't work.

Comment: is working fine for me, I did those steps in 2 browsers

Comment: What I mean is, the menu should hide & show since it's a toggle function. It does show I agree although it won't hide if you click twice or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouseup event was fired before click.
try this

```
$(window).mouseup(function(e){
    if(!menuContainer.is(e.target) && !menuChildren.is(e.target) && !menuBtn.is(e.target)){
        menuContainer.hide();
    }
});
```

[fiddle js](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Dx6/2/)